# Google Chrome could not load the webpage because myPortalapps-12812b1f934c6c.myPortal.apps.com took too long to respond

Tags: 2013

Created a basic sharepoint hosted app, nothing changed, when deploy i get this error message, nothing in uls logs at all,

Trying hello world hosted app but getting this error on deployment,

> Google Chrome could not load the webpage because
>   myPortalapps-12812b1f934c6c.myPortal.apps.com took too long to respond

I can ping `myPortalapps.myPortal.apps.com` but not `myPortalapps-12812b1f934c6c.myPortal.apps.com`

I think this is the issue https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2d85ba9-3b77-4f1c-9888-dabd5903b997/sharepoint-application-gives-error-118-timeout

but not sure how to fix it.

[image]
If the ping command returns the correct IP address, then your wildcard for the domain name was configured successfully.
which they mean by correct ip ????

Comment: yes i am still waiting

Comment: getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in developer tools

Comment: no help so whatever ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did not create your wildcard CNAME-Record in DNS properly. I will try to explain in an example, but as you did not provide your exact DNS-configuration, things might differ a little in your configuration.

I created the Domain "apps.com" in my ActiveDirectory DNS. From there i create a new CNAME "*.myPortal" which points to the Hostname of my SharePoint WebFrontEnd-Server (T-SWF01.sp2013.intern)

[image]

Now please ensure with a PING that your DNS records gets resolved to the correct IP-Address
[image]

If you still get no PING replies, you might want to check your firewall-settings on your SharePoint WebFrontEnd.

Comment: you seen my other question and figured out answer for this - for the effort i am accept it. Happy SP